# Edit email in Ubuntu without X11

Tags: ubuntu, email

**How can you edit the email -field in Ubuntu for a given user?**

I cannot use "gnome-about-me".

Comment: Good question. Try the usermod command, I remember this from ages ago, but can't find any recent relevant info on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file $HOME/.evolution/addressbook/local/system/addressbook.db seems to be where this gnome-about-me information is stored. Apparently that is just a Berkeley DB file; you might be able to do something with the BDB utils directly.

See also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=524028

Comment: I opened the thread about system-wide email at http://superuser.com/questions/78020/unable-to-have-a-system-wide-email . It is what I am trying to achieve.