# Unable to have a system-wide email

Tags: ubuntu, email

My uni has a setting which puts my email address to all programs which I use.
I would like to have a similar setting for me.

For instance, I cannot remember how to set up an email address to mutt.
I would like to have a system-wide setting which gives my email address for mutt.

**How can you set up a system-wide email address in Ubuntu?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you perhaps mean your user account email, so that applications automatically pick up your user's email address by default?

If so, check System -> Preferences -> About Me, and set your default user email address in there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your uni uses some kind of centralised account management, like LDAP or NIS. If you like how they have it set up and you are trying to emulate it for a local server / network, you could try asking your uni's sysadmins directly what they use and how it's set up. It's one of those "many ways to skin a cat" type problems, but an LDAP server might be what you're looking for.